# Distinguishing between a left and right mouse button click in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, click, right-click

Using JavaScript, how can I distinguish between a left and right mouse button click in IE and Firefox? Do I need I need to do anything different between these two browsers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589698/x/589741#589741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `onclick` and `oncontextmenu` events for left-clicks and right-clicks respectively.